# How do I properly error handle?

Tags: python, error-handling

How do I properly write this so that the the output for anything that isn't a number fails the price check and all that prints out is "Not a Valid Price".

Right now, the "Not a Valid Price" part is being updated into the dictionary.

```
name_input=input('OK. Please input the name of the person: ')
system_input=input('OK. Please input the favorite system: ')
line_input=input('OK. Please input the product line: ')
#
try:
    price_input=price_check(input('OK. Please input the product price: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Not a Valid Price')


products1={"id": str(int(products[-1]['id'])+1),
           "name": name_input,
           "system": system_input,
           "line": line_input,
           'price': price_input}
products.append(products1)
```

Comment: Put `products={...} products.append(products1)` into the try block.

Comment: *Right now, the "Not a Valid Price" part is being updated into the dictionary.* What does this mean? The code you posted doesn't do anything like this. Are you capturing the standard output (which of course includes anything you `print()`) into a file perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
def price_check(value):
    if value.isdigit():
        return value
    else:
        return False
```

Then something like this:

```
price_input = false
while not price_input:
    price_input = price_check(input('OK. Please input the product price: '))
    if not price_input:
        print('Invalid input')

products1={"id": str(int(products[-1]['id'])+1),
           "name": name_input,
           "system": system_input,
           "line": line_input,
           'price': price_input}
products.append(products1)
```

This will work if you never want the user to enter an invalid input into the dictionary. You can easily customise this to work with try and excepts but it seems like you may be doing homework so I'll let you figure that out.

If you want it to just print 'invalid' and continue along without saving then you'll want to do:

```
price_input = price_check(input('OK. Please input the product price: '))
if not price_input:
    print('Invalid input')
else:
    products1={"id": str(int(products[-1]['id'])+1),
       "name": name_input,
       "system": system_input,
       "line": line_input,
       'price': price_input}
    products.append(products1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont show the code of method price_check but you onli need write this for validate that you read a integer

```
name_input=input('OK. Please input the name of the person: ')
system_input=input('OK. Please input the favorite system: ')
line_input=input('OK. Please input the product line: ')
#
try:
   price_input=int(input('OK. Please input the product price: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Not a Valid Price')
```

`

with this when you write anything that isn't a integer raise a ValueError exception

Comment: Sorry, price_check was just a simple function that ran a float check. The actual, which I for some reason left out, is that when I do it this way, I get a future error message that price_input has not been defined. Is there a way for me to just kill the code once it's been realized that the price_input is not a number?